# how to set a CompositeTransform to a element e.g. a Ellipse

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to add a 90° Rotation to a Ellipse. So I wrote the following code:

```
CompositeTransform ct = new CompositeTransform();
ct.Rotation = 90;
```

How to append the `CompositeTransform` to a `Ellipse` ellipse?

I tried the following:

```
ellipse.Projection = ct;
```

but this is not working. How to make it right?
The error says:`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.CompositeTransform' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Projection'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `ellipse.RenderTransform = ct`